# ¿ Como congelar y descongelar un jframe?

Tags: java, jframe

Estoy aprendiendo a programar con el lenguaje java y ya estoy usando los JFrame y quisiera saber como al dar click en un boton se ponga otro JFrame en frente y no me deje volver al Primer Jframe hasta que no presione el boton del segundo JFrame

Comment: Cuéntenos ¿Qué intentó ? ¿Donde está teniendo problemas ?. Lo más conveniente sería usar un  `JPanel` y un `JDialog`

Comment: Por experiencia te lo digo varios JFrame te causarán un lío. Lo mejor es, como recomienda @Dev.Joel utilizar JPanel y JDialog. El Jpanel se carga dentro de tu JFrame principal y el JDialog es una ventana que se puede poner en Modal con una linea `miDialogo.setModal(true)`. Eso bastaría para hacer lo que quieres. Con JFrame tendrías que escribir muchísimo código y cosas que al final no te funcionaran como quieres.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar un `JDialog` en lugar de un `JFrame`.

y lo llamas de la siguiente manera

```
MiJDialog midialog = new MiJDialog(**this**,true)
midialog .setVisible(true);
```

Con el **this** garantizas que no se podrá usar el `JFrame` hasta que no se cierre el `Dialog`